# Pagination issue in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am working on angularJS project and implementing pagination using ui-bootstrap-tpls.js pagination directive. But I am facing one issue in this. next and previous buttons are clickable even if they are disabled.

```
You can see the demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/94i0y0PJpHMDTSEF2kXt?p=preview
```

Can you please guide me on this? How to disable click on next and previous button if there is not page further.

Comment: Please post relevant code in the question.

Comment: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/94i0y0PJpHMDTSEF2kXt?p=preview). You can find demo here. Unfortunately I can't able to add url as hyperlink in description.

Answer (score 0):

The disable on next and previous works as intended - You can see that $scope.pageChanged isn't fired. $scope.test is fired because it's attached with `ng-click="test()"` to the paging container itself, and the container is not disabled.

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-click="test()"></pagination>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It help me to find solution on this. I implemented like this `<pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="temp.pageChanged=true" ng-click="temp.pageChanged=true && test()"></pagination>`

Comment: Why do you need this - ng-click="temp.pageChanged=true && test()" - why not just use ng-change?

Comment: Yes That will also work. I will use your logic. Thank for your suggestion.